# How to give access to Intellij-Idea to write files?

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea, file-writing

I am trying to write files to my windows 7 computer using IntelliJ IDEA. I am using the File and Filewriter programs to do this. But I am receiving an error message claiming to not have access to my folders in order to do this.

I have tried looking at other tutorials and people with a similar issue but I have not seen anyone with this issue so far. I have also looked at IntelliJ's permissions in the firewall and they are all in check. I also tried using different derectories such as my SRC folder and others, to no prevail.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //fori loop
        for(int a=0;a<1000;a++) { 
            //writing to desktop
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\BlahBlah\\Desktop\\");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
            fw.write("Hey you!");
            fw.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I should expect a outflow of 1000 files to be written to my pc but instead I get an error telling me "Access is denied". The entire error is listed below.

Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\BlahBlah\Desktop (Access is denied)

Comment: is this a prank software? well, your `jar` need to be run with administrative rights to be able to reach that folder. "**I have also looked at IntelliJ's permissions in the firewall**", the [file permission](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/325361/how-to-configure-security-for-files-and-folders-on-a-network-in-window) is not related to firewall.

Comment: It's not a prank no, I just like doing stupid things like this. I got the problem solved, I didn't put a file name! How could I be so blind! Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is clear, it's telling you that there is not file there. Indeed *C:\Users\BlahBlah\Desktop* is not a file path, you should have something like:

```
file = new File("C:\\Users\\BlahBlah\\Desktop\\test.txt");
```

And you're creating a File 1000 times, I think that you might have an error there as well.

Comment: Oh my goodness, how could i be so blind! Haha! I didn't put a filename! Thank you so much! And my computer will be fine, I've done 100,000 with IntelliJ before!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding index a value to the filename with an extension say desktop1.txt

```
for(int a=0; a<1000;a++)
{
    FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("D:\\ desktop"+a+".txt");
    fw.write("hey file."+a);
fw.close();
}
```